# If return null, failed test Tennis Kata Java

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I found Tennis Kata training for TDD, but I have small problem with If statement.

```
public String getScore(){
    if (server.getScore() >= 3 && receiver.getScore() >= 3){
        if(Math.abs(receiver.getScore() - server.getScore()) >= 2){
            return getLeadPlayer().getName() + " won";
        } else if (Math.abs(server.getScore() - receiver.getScore()) >= 1) {
            return "A" + ":" + receiver.getScoreDescription();
        } else if (Math.abs(receiver.getScore() - server.getScore()) >= 1) {
            return server.getScoreDescription() + ":" + "A";
        } else {
            return "40:40";
        }
    } else {
        return server.getScoreDescription() + ":" + receiver.getScoreDescription();
    }
```

The second else if statement return null. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
@Test
public void receiverAdvantage() {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).forEach((Integer) -> {
        server.winBall();
    });
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).forEach((Integer) -> {
        receiver.winBall();
    });
    assertThat(tennisGame, hasProperty("score", is("40:A")));
}
```

"A" mean advantage.

And the Test result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: hasProperty("score", is "40:A")
 but: null
```

Comment: How getScore related to your test? Why you use Math.abs? It's wrong

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Thank you very much friend, I fixed math abs it was unnecessary. Would you like to look on my another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783902/index-out-of-bound-exception-java

Comment: I believe that assertion error is trying to tell you that `this.tennisGame` has not been initialized.  Your example doesn't show any code that assigns a value to that variable.